# How to get a type of a word field

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-field

I have a Word file with different Fields. I would like to know a type of each field. I know that there is a method called `Field.GetType()` but it is returning something like this : `System.__ComObject`

But I would like to know what `WdFieldType` each field has. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdfieldtype?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_WdFieldType_wdFieldIncludeText

The problem is, that I don't know what filed types people uses. And some field types are causing errors, when I am trying to get Result. 
That's why I would like to exclude those types, but I firstly must know what types there is.

My code:

```cs
foreach (string LeitudNimi in Nimed)
{
    foreach (Field f in doc.Fields)
    {
        if (f.Type != WdFieldType.some field that is causing error)
        {
            if (f.Result.Text.ToLower() == LeitudNimi)
            { 
                f.Result.Text = $"{Nimi}"; 
                f.Unlink(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use that code. I firstly planning to do something like this:

```
foreach (Field f in doc.Fields)
                        {var Type1 = f.GetType()
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\tulemus.txt", $"Field type is: {Type1}" + Environment.NewLine);}
```

Comment: *`String Type1 == f.GetType()`* do you know C# ? ... `GetType()` is `object.GetType()` ... you need get Type properties `var fieldType = f.Type.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am just learning C#. And == was the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be checking the value of `[f.Type]` [(reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.field.type?view=word-pia)  just as you are doing in your first code sample. f.GetType() is returning you the C# object type of the instance held by `f`

```
foreach (Field f in doc.Fields)
{
  File.AppendAllText(@"C:\tulemus.txt", $"Field type is: {f.Type}" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```